# Form with panels using css

Tags: css, forms

I want to achieve a form using css which have different panels for different groups of input fields.

Similar to this.
![alt text][1]

I know this is a desktop client. But is there any way to achieve such a layout with fieldsets css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

```
<form>
  <div id="col1">
    <fieldset id="fldst1"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldst2"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldst3"></fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <fieldset id="fldst4"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldst5"></fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">
    <fieldset id="fldst6"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldst7"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldst8"></fieldset>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;" />
</form>
```

In your CSS:

```
#col1, #col2, #col3 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Then you place the different form elements in your fieldsets.

Comment: could you please be more precise or give an example ?

Comment: Note: When you populate your `fieldsets` start with `<legend>` followed by the elements (which you probably want to place in a definition list `<DL>` or `<table>` first). Alternatively you can set the column width on 33% or any other percentage instead of a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks, It almost works. I say almost because please check what I have here. http://picasaweb.google.com/109557476227180026809/Shots#5542400352325874642     The second row is top aligned and doesn't start from the bottom of the cell above.

Comment: Make sure you reset some default (browser) settings in CSS: `fieldset {margin:0; padding:0;}` and `legend {margin:0; padding:0;}` and use proper margins yourself.

Comment: I am not talking about margins. I just wanted to start the 3rd column in the first row exactly below the 3rd column in the first row and not aligned to the top

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what part of the layout exactly is the problem. You obviously know about `fieldset` and you layout them exactly the same way you would layout any other HTML element (such as `div`).

I'm guessing it the columns. You have two possibilities here. A) Either put a number of `fieldset`s into a div with the width (100% / number of columns) and float those divs, or B) if you only need to support modern browsers use CSS 3 column properties and the browser will calculate the number of `fieldset`s per column for you automatically:

A)

```
#columns .column {
   float: left;
   width: 33%;
}

<div id="columns">
  <div class="column">
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

B)

```
#columns {
   column-count: 3
    /* Just covering all bases here. Not sure which browsers actually support this */
   -webkit-column-count: 3
   -moz-column-count: 3
   -o-column-count: 3
   -ms-column-count: 3
}

<div id="columns">
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Why nest div's in div's? You better nest the divs within the `<form>` tags.

Comment: Please note that method B is a bit tricky because it doesn't have full browser support.

Comment: @Eric: It's just an example. It could be that there are more input elements outside the columns.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Anschrift</legend>

    <label for="nachname">Nachname:</label>
    <input id="nachname" name="nachname" type="text">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
   <legend>Firmenanschrift</legend>

    <label for="firma">Firma:</label>
    <input id="firma" name="firma" type="text">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
   <legend>Einkommen</legend>

    <label for="jaresgehalt">Jaresgehalt:</label>
    <input id="jaresgehalt" name="jaresgehalt" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: If you look closely at this example picture you see he doesn't want 3 fieldsets next to eachother but 3 columns, and in those columns fieldsets need to be placed.